# st_read fails to read from database

Tags: postgis, r, sf

I need to read multi-polygon data stored in PostGIS database into R. Having successfully established the connection (let's say `con`), I tried to read using sf::st_read and dbi::dbGetQuery

using `dbi::dbGetQuery`

```
dbGetQuery(con, 'Select * FROM "my_schema"."my_table"')
```

works fine.

using `sf::st_read`

```
st_read(con, 'Select * FROM "my_schema"."my_table"')
```

fails with the following error message

```
Error in nchar(sm[1L], type = "w") : invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

Slightly modified query

```
st_read(con, "Select * FROM my_schema.my_table")
```

still fails!

Is there something wrong with my query? If so how come it works when using dbGetQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [st_read](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_read.html) function uses `layer`as a second argument. To avoid error, and because often libraries can change arguments of functions, you should always uses named arguments instead of positionnal ones, at least after the first argument which usually never changes.

The proper call should be `st_read(con, query = "SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table")`

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice this silly thing

Comment: It's easy to make this kind of errors, that's why the recommanded way of passing arguments is by naming them, at least when you make production-ready code. Languages like Python and R are permissive, so it's normal that's easier to make mistakes with them :)